# How do you start custom non-UI threads on a Netbeans platform application?

Tags: netbeans-platform

**Q**: How do you start custom non-UI threads on a Netbeans platform application?

This was never a problem for me with swing applications since I had a main class to work with.

Here is how I used to do it.

```
//Execute main method.
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    //Start thread 1.
    (new Thread(new ThreadClass1())).start();
    //Start thread 2.
    (new Thread(new ThreadClass2())).start();
    //Start thread 3.
    (new Thread(new ThreadClass3())).start();
}
```

I do prefer the net-beans platform but it manages much of these start up functions differently than what I am used to. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: By custom thread, do you mean stopping the Netbeans `main window/top component`, and starting your own JFrame/thread instead ? If that´s the case, there is a way to stop the Netbeans main window altogether, just add the following parameter inside the start up config file-
`default_options="-J-Dorg.netbeans.core.WindowSystem.show=false"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and I thought to write it out.

I have a class called StartupClass.java  and you need to declare it in the module manifest as:

```
OpenIDE-Module-Install: parentFolder/StartupClass.class
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.openide.modules.ModuleInstall;

public class StartupClass extends ModuleInstall 
{
    //This method is executed at startup.
    @Override
    public void restored()
    {
        //Start thread 1.
        (new Thread(new ThreadClass1())).start();
        //Start thread 2.
        (new Thread(new ThreadClass2())).start();
        //Start thread 3.
        (new Thread(new ThreadClass3())).start();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ThreadClass1().start()
```

this is the default way to start your threads.